# Read file format using C/C++ in a proper manner

Tags: c++, file, format

How would you go about reading a simple file format using C or C++?

For example, take the Wavefront .obj file format, sample:

```
# this is a box

o 1

v -0.5 -0.5 0.5
v -0.5 -0.5 -0.5
v -0.5 0.5 -0.5
v -0.5 0.5 0.5
v 0.5 -0.5 0.5
v 0.5 -0.5 -0.5
v 0.5 0.5 -0.5
v 0.5 0.5 0.5

usemtl Default
f 4 3 2 1
f 2 6 5 1
f 3 7 6 2
f 8 7 3 4
f 5 8 4 1
f 6 7 8 5
```

Since the files can be quite large, I made an intermediate class (FileBuffer) with an operator[]. It only every has 4096 bytes of the file in memory, and reads new parts whenever needed.
The file format is really simple, but I don't prefer to use something like flex/bison for this. It would only complicate matters.

What would be a proper way to go about interpreting this (kind of) file? Currently I have a whole lot of nested for/while loops and many counters keeping track. Also many switch/elseif statements. How would I make this code maintainable and more structured overall?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? They are different languages and the solutions provided are likely to be different as well.

Comment: @Rob Adams the OP "made an intermediate class with an operator[]", sounds like C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908854/opengl-problem-with-texture-in-model-from-obj/2909187#2909187 might provide a reasonable starting point.

Comment: Removed the [c] tag as inconsistent with *"I made an intermediate class (FileBuffer) with an `operator[]`."*

Comment: I was actually also interested in a C approach, but C++ is preferred ;). Adams way looks like a simple approach I never thought of :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I'd leverage as much of the standard library as I could:

```
struct Command { /* Abstract Base Class */ ... };
struct VCommand : Command { std::vector<double> dims; ... }
struct FCommand : Command { std::vector<int> vertexes; ... }
struct FootCommand : Command { enum {LEFT, RIGHT, IN, OUT} e; ... }
std::vector<Command*> commandList; // DANGER: raw pointers
void ParseInput(std::istream& in) {
    // untested code:
    std::string line;
    while(getline(in, line)) {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string command;
        lineStream >> command;
        if(command == "v") {
            std::istream_iterator<double>(lineStream) begin;
            std::istream_iterator<double> end;

            // Add the "v" command to the parse tree
            commandList.push_back(new VCommand(begin, end));
        } else if (command == "f") {
            std::istream_iterator<int>(lineStream) begin;
            std::istream_iterator<int> end;

            // Add the "v" command to the parse tree
            commandList.push_back(new FCommand(begin, end));
        } else if (command == "quit") {
            ...
        } else if (command == "put_your_left_foot_in") {
            ...
            commandList.push_back(new FootCommand(LEFT, IN));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sstream` is deprecated if favor of `stringstream`

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Thanks! It seems like I get those two confused every time I mention one (or the other). I edited the post.

Comment: the plural of "vertex" is "vertices", not "vertexes".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the format correctly, each line defines
a specific type of data, with the type determined by the first
word.  I'd start by defining an abstract base class and
a concrete instance of the class for each type of line; I'd
register these instances in a `std::map<std::string,
LineParser*>`.

For reading the file, I'd probably install a filtering streambuf
to get rid of the comments and the empty lines upstream.  Then
a simple loop would do the trick:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( filteredInput, line ) ) {
    std::string keyword;
    std::istringstream toParse( line );
    toParse >> keyword;
    std::map<std::string, LineParser*>::const_iterator
        parser = registry.find( keyword );
    if ( parser == registry.end() ) {
        //  Syntax error: unknown keyword...
    } else {
        parser->parse( toParse );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with defining (or obtaining) the file grammar/structure.

Then build a parser for the input stream based on that grammar.